# QGIS crash: delete column in GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geopackage, log

QGIS crashes without error or log massage as soon I try to delete a column in a GeoPackage using the attribute table:

[image]

How could I find out, what's going on in background of QGIS?

Installed QGIS3 on Mint 18.3 (Xenial) with ubuntu-gis-unstable repos

Comment: SQLite does not natively support "ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN" https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html and that is what you basically want to do. I quess that QGIS developers have tried to make their own implementation but it fails for you. Even if it works the operation requires to write the whole contents of the table into a new table and drop table - rename table after that. It may feel annoying but it might be better to keep the extra fields until you have done all the edits and then create a totally new table by picking just the fields that you want.

Comment: Okay, understand - I did something infeasible, but a crash without error message is still questionable. But my question is answered.

Comment: I agree, it should not crash but I told some background. You should report the crash to QGIS developers.